# std::visit Vs For_each loop

Tags: visitor-pattern

Let the data structure be anything (Array, Vectors, Std::Variant). But what is the difference in traversing using just for/for_each against std::visit.

```
for (auto& Element: collection){
        std::visit([](auto arg){std::cout << arg << " ";}, Element);
    
}
```

And

```
for_each(collection.begin(), collection.end(), [](Element& e)
{
   std::cout << e;
});
```

Note1: I know C-style for loop vs C++ for_each..For_each avoids typo error/syntactic sugar. so we can be happy with just for_each.

Note2: I know visitor design pattern too, which will be used for polymorphic object against polymorphic behaviour.

But still I couldn't appreciate and understand **std::visit**.

And when I digged further, I came to know something called **Overload pattern**.

```
template<typename ... Ts>                                                
struct Overload : Ts ... { 
    using Ts::operator() ...;
};
template<class... Ts> Overload(Ts...) -> Overload<Ts...>;
```

But this Overload pattern too can be done using the same for_each right?

Thanks in advance for the reply.,

Answer (score 0):

The difference between your first and second method is that the second does not work if your collection elements are variants. The example below compiles and lists your options.

Methods 2 and 4 are the only elegant ones I believe. But Method 2 is limited (see how it prints) while Method 4 gives you all the flexibility you may wish for.

But this does not necessarily mean Method 4 is the way to go. Place some intentional errors in Method 4 and then look at the error messages. They are mostly unintelligible.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
#include <variant>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using Element = std::variant<int, std::string>;
using Collection = std::vector<Element>;
Collection c = {1, 2, "three", "four", 5};

auto print_int = [](int const & e)
{
    std::cout << "int: " << e << std::endl;
};

auto print_str = [](std::string const & e)
{
    std::cout << "string: " << e << std::endl;
};

auto print_any = [](auto && e)
{
    std::cout << "element: " << e << std::endl;
};

void Method1 ()
{
    for (Element const & e: c)
    {
        {
            auto const * i = std::get_if<int>(&e);
            if (i)
            {
                print_int(*i);
                continue;
            }
        }
        {
            auto const * s = std::get_if<std::string>(&e);
            if (s)
            {
                print_str(*s);
                continue;
            }
        }
    }
}

void Method2 ()
{
    for (Element const & e: c)
    {
        std::visit(print_any, e);
    }
}

void Method3 ()
{
    std::for_each(c.cbegin(), c.cend(), [](Element const & e)
    {
       std::visit(print_any, e);
    });
}

template<class... Ts> struct overloaded : Ts... { using Ts::operator()...; };
template<class... Ts> overloaded(Ts...) -> overloaded<Ts...>;
void Method4 ()
{
    for (Element const & e: c)
    {
        std::visit(overloaded
        {
            [](int i) { print_int(i); },
            [](std::string s) { print_str(s) ; }
        }, e);
    }
}

int main ()
{
    std::cout << std::endl << "Method1" << std::endl;
    Method1();
    std::cout << std::endl << "Method2" << std::endl;
    Method2();
    std::cout << std::endl << "Method3" << std::endl;
    Method3();
    std::cout << std::endl << "Method4" << std::endl;
    Method4();
}
```